# Why isn't a Stack Overflow question title inserted automatically when pasting a link to that question in the comment?

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, title

When inserting the question link into a post (question/answer), it will automatically be resolved to the question title. For example

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22126073/multiword-addition-in-c
```

will be resolved to

> [Multiword addition in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22126073/multiword-addition-in-c)

But, if I comment the above link, it will still be a link without the link title, that is,

> [stackoverflow.com/questions/22126073/multiword-addition-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22126073/multiword-addition-in-c)

or something like that, with the text being truncated if the link is too long.

Why is that? Why can't Stack Overflow replace the link title on comment either? That will make it more readable and shorter.

Comment: [SE Comment Link Helper](http://stackapps.com/q/2378). In any case, comments are second-class citizens.

Comment: And cross-site dupe: [Replace links with the current question title in comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77394) where Jeff Atwood (original Stack Overflow founder) explains his motivations against it. Not a lot of people agreed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: *"Not a lot of people agreed."* You shock me.

Answer (score 27):

Completely agree, and five years later, we can say that [this request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77394) and its [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) are arcane.

Comments are ephemeral second-class citizens, but that doesn't mean that links in them should be semi-blind.

I'd even be tempted to take it further, and automatically replace *all* raw links (in comments, questions, answers) with the title of the page they link to (via a server-side query) at the point when the markdown is posted (e.g., so it doesn't have to be repeated, and captures the moment in time).

Comment: _"a server-side query"_ - that can be abused. For every browser, there's a plugin called "Title Copy" or similar.

Comment: Of course, and I think it'd be a nice feature. The possibility for abuse in letting a server execute an HTTP request to a user-supplied URI may hold back the eagerness with which SE will implement this feature, that's what I meant to say.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Apologies, coincidentally deleted my comment to rephrase seconds before you posted. :-) (Lurkers: it was basically "Anything can be abused" and the system can cope as it does with other forms of abuse.)

Comment: Re *"...a plugin called "Title Copy"*: An alternative, in Firefox: menu *Tools* → *Page Info* (or Ctrl + I), Tab (to select the content of the "Title" field), and Ctrl + C. E.g., for this page: *"Why isn't a Stack Overflow question title inserted automatically when pasting a link to that question in the comment? - Meta Stack Overflow"*