# When posting raw question links in comments, add the question title

Tags: feature-request, comments, hyperlinks

While browsing questions, I frequently find myself linking to other questions in the comments. For example, I might close vote a question as a duplicate, but also link several other questions that could also be possible duplicate targets. Sometimes the question is only really a duplicate if you put 2 or 3 questions together.

The problem is that linking to other questions is a huge pain. Once I find a question I want to link to, the process is quite painful:

1. Click on share, copy link.
2. Switch tabs back where I want to leave a comment.
3. Write `[](`, then paste.
4. Navigate back to the tab.
5. Carefully select the title of the question to copy it. As the title is a link, it takes extra care to ensure I don't click on it.
6. Navigate back to my comment tab, potentially closing this new tab in the process
7. Carefully click inside of the `[]` and paste. Oftentimes, there's extra whitespace before or after so I have to manually delete that.

Yes, the process becomes *slightly* better if I were to copy the title before the link, but I usually forget that, and it's not good enough anyway. Switching between tabs is very expensive, as I usually have many tabs open, frequently in between the two tabs I need to alternate between.

If I left the title off, the process is easy again, but then it becomes harder to follow the comment, especially if you have multiple links in a row:

[image]

I want Stack Overflow to do the work for me. I know there's a [stack app](https://stackapps.com/q/2378/51507) for it, but this behavior should really be native in Stack Overflow (it's not always possible to use the stack app). All it needs to do is – if the link is to Stack Overflow – change `https://stackoverflow.com/...` into `[Title of Post](https://stackoverflow.com/...)`, it doesn't have to do anything expensive like [Jeff Atwood suggested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86909/218012) when this was brought up on Meta Stack Exchange.

---

Note: this was requested a few years ago (yes, 2015 was 3 years ago) but got no response from a dev or community manager:

[Why isn't a Stack Overflow question title inserted automatically when pasting a link to that question in the comment?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284987/1896169)

In contrast to that question, I do outline some motivation behind this feature request.

Comment: Notice that stack overflow contained links from comments will be represented in the _related section_ anyways (with correctly rendered title). I'm supporting _auto title deduction_ for the restricted markdown anyways.

Comment: @TheDude That is a good point. I almost never look there unless I'm specifically wondering about related posts, though....

Comment: @TheDude That's not necessarily true. The links must be to a fully qualified URL. [Neither protocol-relative URLs, nor relative URLs, are recognized by the system as pointing to questions to be added to the sidebar's "Linked" list.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291236/protocol-relative-and-relative-urls-should-be-considered-linked) BTW: I assume you meant "Linked", not "Related", in the sidebar.

Comment: @Makyen _"BTW: I assume you meant "Linked", not "Related""_ Sure, I meant that, THX for clarification.

Comment: IIRC, if I VTC as duplicate, the generated comment says, `Possible duplicate of [Title of Question](link-to-question)`. That information might be relevant to this feature-request, but I don't want to edit it in unless I can confirm it

Comment: On a tangential note: be careful when suggesting dupes like that -- your lovingly written comments might be [eaten up by the system](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344519/2751851).

Comment: @duplode Funnily enough, I've never been bit by that. Most of my comments of that form are "Related: <links>" or "Other possible dupe targets: <links>". I've never actually written the word "duplicate" for additional comments

Comment: @Justin That's fortunate :) Another paraphrase I like is "suggested question".

Comment: _"as I usually have many tabs open, frequently in between the two tabs I need to alternate between"_ - Use Ctrl+Tab to easily switch between your two most recently active tabs. (May require checking a box in your browser's options to enable this behavior -- look for "Use most-recently-used tab order" or similar. Not supported at all in Chrome.)

Comment: @duplode Hmm, I had no idea comments containing the word dupl***** were auto-deleted. I guess from now on I'll put extra information in a separate comment when flagging. Good to know.

Comment: @JonSchneider I actually strongly dislike that behaviour; I'm never going to turn that setting on. I can never predict what tab I'm going to go to when that setting is on. But yeah it could be helpful

Comment: @Justin Fair enough! :-) For me personally, it's a must-have feature, similar to Alt+Tab / Cmd+Tab to flip between open _applications_ in MRU order. It's the single reason why I don't use Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since posting this question, I have been testing it out. I have stopped doing the fancy link formatting. Rather than writing

```
[When posting raw question links in comments, add the question title](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/363395/1896169)
```

I've just been posting the link directly:

```
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/363395/1896169
```

In this short, informal experiment, I have seen no difference in posting links the two different ways. In the Question, I was operating under the premise that posting the title of the linked question would improve understanding of my comments and thus improve my communication with people reading my comment. In this month, I have seen no evidence to support that.

It seems like formatting comment links in this way has **only the effect of making me feel good about the "pretty formatting" of my comments.**