# Can we have automatic pretty links to questions in comments?

Tags: support, feature-request, comments, markdown, hyperlinks

I adore that you can write a link to a Stack Exchange question in a post like: `https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/5740428` and it automatically expands to [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/5740428)

Is there a way to do that in [comment Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) too? I wasn't able to find anything on the topic, and it would save me a lot of effort if this was possible.

I know that you could write `[Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/5740428)` but that's obviously more effort and can get out of sync with the question title after edits take place.

Comment: Note that there is a (ancient) feature request over on SE Meta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77394/replace-links-with-the-current-question-title-in-comments Sadly, this was declined back then. There's also a (slightly less ancient) feature quested on SO Meta: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284987/why-isnt-a-stack-overflow-question-title-inserted-automatically-when-pasting-a Sadly, that one just gathers dust.